# Set PHP session with AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

After a week of trial and error with lots of reading here, I still can't get this working.
What I want to do:
I have a website with 24 product pages. Each product is available in "classic" or "moderne". Each page will have a clickable button to switch between one and the other (display a different img, essentially). If a user clicks to see Product A in "moderne", then moves on to Product B, I want them to see the "moderne" version directly without having to click again (the default display being "classic"). I think SESSION is exactly what I need.
My code (I AM using session_start() at the top of both pages):

Product A page:

```
<?php
$_SESSION["collection"] = ""; 

?>

<script> 
function ClasstoMod(){
        $(".classique, .moderne").toggle(); // toggles the images, it's working
        }
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#display-moderne" ).click(function() {
        request = 
            $.ajax({
                url: "classtomod.php",
                type: "post",
                data: 'moderne'
                });
        // callback handler that will be called on success 
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){            
        // log a message to the console 
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");      });         
        // callback handler that will be called on failure  
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){             
        // log the error to the console 
        console.error(              "The following error occured: "+                textStatus, errorThrown             );          }); }); 
});
</script>
<html>
<div id="display-moderne" class="classique" href="#" onclick="ClasstoMod();">Check out the new Moderne Line!</div>
    <div id="display-classique" style="display:none;" class="moderne" href="#" onclick="ClasstoMod();">Return to our Classique Line!</div>
</html>
```

classtomod.php

```
<?php
$_SESSION['collection'] = $_POST['data'];

?>
```

Product B page, for now I'm only trying to echo the right "collection", I'll work on the JS to display the proper image later!

```
<?php 
echo "Collection = " .$_SESSION['collection']; 
?>
```

The console log is successful, however the echo on Page B does not echo the new SESSION. 
If I run it as shown, it simply echoes "Collection = "
If I define $_SESSION['collection'] = "test" on Page A, Page B echoes "Collection = test" as expected, so that part is working.
What I want is, after I click on #display-moderne is for Page B to echo "Collection = moderne"

I think I'm close, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're missing `session_start();` in the PHP scripts.

Comment: You might want to look into local storage or cookies also unless you really need a reason to have the server hold the session.

Comment: @Barmar I have session_start at the top of all pages, before the doctype.

Comment: @Rob, do you think cookies are easier to "make it work"? or is just better practice for this?

Comment: I would say better practice.  There's really no reason for the server to hold this session when it's based on a users preference.  Local storage or a cookie would be just fine, however, local storage compatibility, although better, is not used in all browsers.

Comment: These are the kind of things cookies and local storage are for.  Created a local storage example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvcotu29/

Comment: Thank you, Rob. I do like the fact that it's all JS, no ajax. I will certainly try it.

Comment: @user2877438 no problem.  I updated the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Lvcotu29/) to show the applicable divs.  Glad you found your session answer.  Choices are good :)

Comment: @Rob, even better, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the name of the `POST` parameter in your AJAX call. It should be:

```
data: { data: 'moderne'}
```

or

```
data: 'data=moderne'
```

Comment: well, there you go, I knew it was something simple. THANK YOU! works great, now to display the right divs based on the session.